# "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18" is thrown when chrome extension use "EventSrouce" is initialized

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xss

I'm using HTML5 Sever Send Event to publish some status of the server. And I'm implementing a chrome extension to track the status, and notify user if needed.

But When I'm trying to create the EventSource object
Chrome throws exception "Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"

```
var tracker = (function(url) {
    var source = new EventSource(url);
    var onMessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    source.addEventListener('new', onMessage);

    return {
        source: source,
        newMessage: onMessage
    };
})('http://localhost:3000/dispatching');
```

And I do added the url of the server into my extension permissions:

```
"permissions": [ 
    "http://localhost:3000/",
    "tabs"
]
```

But the permission doesn't really solve the problem!
Any idea?

Comment: Which URL is your page hosted at? Is it a different port?

Comment: I'm not sure how they deal with ports but your [match pattern](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) should be `http://localhost:3000/*` in order to work. **However**, I don't believe that this permission is even required to call processes running locally on the machine (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615089/how-adobe-shadow-chrome-extension-be-able-to-catch-dom-changes-without-any-relev)) so I think the problem may lie with your code. Unfortunately, I don't know much about this new API yet so can't really help there.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue occuring to HTML files loaded through the `file://` protocol trying to contact the server via the `http://` protocol.

Here is [an article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy) describing how to bypass SOP for your development environment.

When you go into production, my understanding is that that google chrome provides certain ways to by-pass the usual SOP restrictions normally imposed on browsers. This may be through the `permissions` JSON you mentioned however I'm not familiar enough with Chrome Extensions to say for certain.

Ah, hold on, [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051537/how-to-disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome-extension) might be useful.